# need to ignore decimal places from string if decimal places is .00

Tags: c#, number-formatting

Hello Everyone I want to *ignore* this `.00` from string number. Below is my sample input and need output. I have tried this code. `String.Format ("{0: n}", Amount)` but problem in this code.

If value is `10000. 00`.
My code will convert it into `"10, 000.00"`
but I need only `"10, 000"`.

Please help me to fix the issue.

**More examples:**

```
10000.00  -> "10,000"
10000.12  -> "10,000.12"
10000.1   -> "10,000.10"
```

Comment: What should we output on `10000.1` *one* digit after the decimal point?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i need this 10000.1 so it will be 10000.10

Comment: I see; it seems that you have to *switch* between the formats and this is the actual problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have some kind of *money*: we output *cents* if and only if we have them:

```
  10000.00  -> 10,000    (no cents; exactly 10000)
  10000.003 -> 10,000    (no cents; still exactly 10000) 
  10000.1   -> 10,000.10 (ten cents)
  10000.12  -> 10,000.12 (twelve cents)
  10000.123 -> 10,000.12 (still twelve cents)
```

The last three cases we can format out as `"#,0.00"` and the first two will be correct with `"#,0"` format string. The only problem is to *distinguish* the cases.

We can try using `Math.Round()` for this

```
  string result = d.ToString(Math.Round(d) != Math.Round(d, 2) ? "#,0.00" : "#,0");
```

**Demo:**

```
decimal[] tests = new decimal[] {
  10000.00m,
  10000.003m,
  10000.10m,
  10000.12m,
  10000.123m,
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(d => 
     $"{d,-10} -> {d.ToString(Math.Round(d) != Math.Round(d, 2) ? "#,0.00" : "#,0")}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
10000.00   -> 10,000
10000.003  -> 10,000
10000.10   -> 10,000.10
10000.12   -> 10,000.12
10000.123  -> 10,000.12
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this format `String.Format ("{0:0.##}", Amount)`

Or with thousand separator: `"{0:#,0.##}"` by @Dmitry Bychenko

Comment: Thousand (group) separator: `"{0:#,0.##}"`

Comment: i also need this  10000.1 so it will be 10000.10

Answer (score 0):

Convert to integer will remove your decimal places and N2 formatting will be used as thousand separator.

```
([int]10000.00).ToString("N");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just add another extension

```
        var Amount = "1000.00";
        var r = String.Format("{0: n}", Amount).Replace(".00", "");
```